# How to reconsume a rejected message later, RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Sometimes due to some external problems, I need to requeue a message by basic.reject with requeue = true.

But I don't need to consume it immediately because it will possibly fail again in a short time. If I continuously requeue it, this may result in infinite loop and requeue.

1. So I need to consume it later, say one minute later,
2. And I need to know how many times the messages has been requeue so that I can stop requeue it but only reject it to declare it fails to consume.

PS: I am using Java client.

Comment: Regarding your second question. You can add counter to message itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to point 1.

First one is the one chosen by [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org) (a Python producer/consumer library that can use RabbitMQ as broker). Inside your message, add a timestamp at which the task should be executed. When your consumer gets the message, do not ack it and check its timestamp. As soon as the timestamp is reached, the worker can execute the task. (Note that the worker can continue working on other tasks instead of waiting)
This technique has some drawbacks. You have to increase the QoS per channel to an arbitrary value. And if your worker is already working on a long running task, the delayed task wont be executed until the first task has finished.

A second technique is RabbitMQ-only and is much more elegant. It takes advantage of [dead-letter exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) and [Messages TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html). You create a new queue which isn't consumed by anybody. This queue has a dead-letter exchange that will forward the messages to the consumer queue. When you want to defer a message, ack it (or reject it without requeue) from the consumer queue and copy the message into the dead-lettered queue with a TTL equal to the delay you want (say one minute later). At (roughly) the end of TTL, the defered message will magically land in the consumer queue again, ready to be consumed. RabbitMQ team has also made the [Delayed Message Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/) (this plugin is marked as `experimental yet fairly stable and potential suitable for production use as long as the user is aware of its limitations` and has serious limitations in term of scalability and reliability in case of failover, so you might decide whether you really want to use it in production, or if you prefer to stick to the manual way, limited to one TTL per queue).

Point 2. just requires putting a counter in your message and handling this inside your app. You can choose to put this counter in a header or directly in the body.